# PyQt5 GUI got an error message only on server / "QPaintDevice::metrics: Device has no metric information"

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt, pyqt5

I've created GUI app with PyQt5 and it runs properly on my desktop PC (windows10 pro) but I copied the app to the server(windows10 pro/not connected to monitor) and run it, I got the following error message.

```
QPaintDevice::metrics: Device has no metric information
```

I can't understand what it means.

My desktop and server has the same anaconda environment.

Even more confusing, the app runs properly on the server if I run it on pycharm debug mode(using pydev debugger).

Here's the part of code. I'm trying to embed matplotlib figure object to PyQt5 GUI.

The last row is exactly where I got the error message.

```
TempLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.ui.wMainChart)
TempLayout.setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1)
TempFigure = Figure()
TempFigureCanvas = FigureCanvas(TempFigure)
```

Comment: It's just a warning, it's not a mistake, forget it